# Show one diagonal of $B D E C$ divides the other diagonal in the ratio?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

Consider a triangle $A B C$. The sides $A B$ and $A C$ are extended to points $D$ and $E,$ respectively, such that $A D=3 A B$ and $A B=3 A C$. Then one diagonal of $B D E C$ divides the other diagonal in the ratio ?

*My approach*

I am trying to find the relatio between BOC and and DOE (O is the intersecting point of the diagonals).
But I am unable to do so. Although the ratio of AD/AB = AE/AC , I can't show  $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADE$  are equivalent.
Am i going wrong?

Comment: What info do we have about $E$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you mean that $AE=3AC.$ If that is the case, then $\triangle ABC\sim \triangle ADE,$ so $BC$ is parallel to $DE.$ By the theorem on a transversal intersecting parallel lines, $\angle BCD=\angle CDE$ and $\angle CBE=\angle BED.$ So $$\triangle BOC\sim \triangle EOD.$$ By similarity ratios, $$\frac{BO}{EO}=\frac{CO}{DO}.$$ Is that what you were seeking?